# Someone only upvoted my question once I accepted their answer (probably). Is this proper conduct?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes

On a question, I asked there was only one answer posted. It didn't really completely answer my question, so I did some further research and answered my own question. I accepted my answer because it was the only satisfactory answer posted.

Then the other answer that was posted was edited by the person who posted it, adding another point to it. That answer was so much better than my answer now that I accepted it instead.

Then I noticed I gained 2 rep from that question and then plus 10. Apparently, at the same time that I accepted that dude's answer, someone canceled their downvote on my question, then upvoted it. So the most likely either the guy whose answer I accepted or somebody else who liked their answer better only upvoted my question once I accepted their answer.

Is this proper conduct? Should people be doing this?

And just to be clear, I'm not accusing anyone of anything. There is no actual evidence that someone did this. I'm only asking here so I can know for myself whether or not I should do this. I DO NOT want to get ANYBODY in trouble.

Comment: You get +2 rep when you accept an answer to your question that isn’t your own. I can see that event in your rep history. Are you sure that isn’t the +2 you’re talking about?

Comment: Also anyone’s free to vote how they please, short of voting fraud. This isn’t exactly the best way to vote on things, if true, but the user isn’t breaking any rules here.

Comment: You might also want to note that **constantly** beating the drum and being dramatic about every perceived setback will tend to encourage a certain element to downvote you (regardless of question or answer quality), just to see if they can get a rise out of you.

Comment: @Valorum You might want to note that I'm not trying to be "dramatic" I'm trying to find out exactly how I'm supposed to behave on SE. Note that I was asking this as what would be proper conduct for ME to do.

"I'm only asking here so I can know for myself whether or not I should do this."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say this:

> Then I noticed I gained 2 rep from that question and then plus 10. Apparently, at the same time that I accepted that dude's answer, someone canceled their downvote on my question, then upvoted it. So the most likely either the guy whose answer I accepted or somebody else who liked their answer better only upvoted my question once I accepted their answer.

Honestly that whole chunk of your question gave me a headache. Why do you believe some series of events like that has any meaning past what it is: Votes changed based on content changing.

> Is this proper conduct? Should people be doing this?

Anyone can vote anyway here for any reason. Votes are an indication of personal opinion.

And the case of some questions, I only upvote a question if I answer the question and the answer is well received. I don’t do this to be political or to hold reputation hostage, but rather I do it because in *some* cases, a question might be misinterpreted by me, yet I have an answer. I will post an answer and maybe follow up with:

> “I wasn’t 100% clear with what your question is, but I tried to answer it as best as possible. Let me know if I understood it correctly.”

If my interpretation of the question is correct and my answer is valid, I will only upvote that question *afterwards* to assure I am not rewarding a question that is too confusing to truly be well understood.

And in the case of someone coming in *after* you self-answered, that is normal. If you clearly state you know what you know and your answer “Is what it is…” then someone else can come along and go, “Wait! There is more…”

Nothing that happened on your question is problematic but rather you are seeing the side effect of someone getting a better answer than was expected and someone else looking at that question and going, “Oh! That is a good question…”

Chances are always equal that when a new answer is posted, a new set of eyes sees the question, then sees the answer and simply they are outside of your internalized dramatic interpretation and simply like it as is.

This is a community of people. Getting upset or concerned about one or two upvotes or downvotes is silly. The reason some people have high reps is not because every single thing they post is amazing, but because they continue to post, participate and be a part of the community.

Sure, sometimes someone posts a question that is sure to always get attention and votes, but even people with amazingly well received questions still get downvotes.

As Bobby McFerrin once sang, don’t worry… Be happy…

Comment: Au contraire. Every single thing I post *is* amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Absent evidence of intentional [abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), people can up or downvote a question or answer however they please, for whatever reason they choose or whatever rationale they personally employ.

While we're on the subject, might I strongly suggest you shouldn't sweat a *single* up or downvote as these can often occur as a result of [fat fingers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-finger_error) anyway. Instead, concentrate on writing sensible questions and well-referenced answers that will attract lots of upvotes from your fellow users.

Comment: Yeah, that might have been the +2 rep I got.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Firestryke - New users tend to obsess on downvotes until they realise that the trick to getting oodles of upvotes is to a) be quick, b) be reasonable and c) reference the hell out of everything.

Comment: Fat fingers or [lost keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/278659), to borrow an SE meme. Main meta also has a [list of reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/278659) why people *might* vote on something, not all good ones.